# Problems pointers and ordered lists in C

Tags: c, pointers, osdev

I'm working on an operating system. I'm currently working on memory management. I have a `struct` that models an ordered list of pointers:

```
typedef struct
{
  void* *list;
  uint32_t size;
  uint32_t max_size;
  lessthan_predicate_t less_than;
} ordered_list_t;
```

I have a function that inserts something at the correct spot in the ordered list:

```
void insert_ordered_list(void* item, ordered_list_t *ordered_list)
{
  uint32_t i=0;
  while (i < ordered_list->size && ordered_list->less_than(ordered_list->list[i], item))
  {
    i++;
  }
  if (i == ordered_list->size)
    {
      // just add it to the end of the list
      ordered_list->list[i] = item;
      fb_printf("We got passed: %h", item);   <=== Returns 0xe08000
      fb_printf("We stored: %h", ordered_list->list[i]); <=== Returns 0x0
```

This function places the ordered list:

```
ordered_list_t place_ordered_list(void *addr, uint32_t max_size, lessthan_predicate_t less_than)
{
  ordered_list_t to_ret;
  to_ret.list = (void*)addr;
  memset(to_ret.list, 0, max_size*sizeof(type_t));
  to_ret.size = 0;
  to_ret.max_size = max_size;
  to_ret.less_than = less_than;
  return to_ret;
 }
```

My list is initialized like this:

```
heap->index = place_ordered_list((void*)start, HEAP_INDEX_SIZE, &address_less_than);
```

The first item `header` is then pushed into the list like this:

```
insert_ordered_list((void*)header, &heap->index);
```

I am storing `item` in the `ordered_list->list` at index `i`. However, the last line that reads and prints that exact location returns `0x0`, while `item` is `0xE08000`. What am I missing? Why isn't the value of `item` stored in the array? Any suggestions?

Comment: `sizeof(void*) == sizeof(type_t)` ?

Comment: What is the definition of `type_t`? Also, `%h` normally specifies a `short int`. What is the size of `short` on your platform (am asking as you are showing more than 16 bit for `item`)?

Comment: yes. they are the same (`typedef void* type_t;`). I'll clarify the example.

Comment: `%h` is typed to an `uint32_t`

Comment: Use `%p` for a (void*) pointer.

Comment: Ok. And are you sure you are not overflowing the `list` array? Does it always exhibit that behaviour or only sometimes? Have you printed `item` immediately before the last line in the code shown? These are all basic questions but since you have not provided an MCVE or explicitly stated that then they need to be asked.

Comment: try `fb_printf("We got passed: %h", (uint32_t)item);` and `fb_printf("We stored: %h", (uint32_t)ordered_list->list[i]);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY that returns the same values as before..

Comment: @kaylum So far it always seems to be doing this. I've put the printf for item directly before the last one (i'll update question). I don't fully understand the overflowing remark...

Comment: What I mean by the overflowing comment is to ask what the allocated size of the `list` array is and what the value of `i` is. It may also be worth providing the code that does the `list` allocation. Also, at this point I think we are all just shooting blindly (due to not having the full picture). It may be best if you attempt to provide some minimal and complete code to demonstrate the problem. Even if not for SO it would still be beneficial for your own sake to have minimal code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @kaylum `i` is 0 at this time, but i also tried it with a hard value (0,1,2). I've added the code that places the array and the code that calls the insert

Comment: What is the value of `start` and what is the value of `HEAP_INDEX_SIZE`? Please show your code that allocates space for the list (e.g.,  by calling `malloc()`).

Comment: @MarcKhadpe `start` is `0xe00000` and `HEAP_INDEX_SIZE` is `0x2000`. As this code is part of the memory manager there is no `malloc` (this code implements it). The index is placed in a free memory area and the area is NULLd.

Comment: @ErwinM So `start` and `header` point to the same data? That doesn't sound right. How are you allocating memory for the list?

Comment: @MarcKhadpe `0xe00000 to 0xe08000` holds the ordered list of pointers (the hole list) that indexed the heap memory that runs from `0xe08000` to `0x1000000`.

Comment: try  `printf("We got passed: %p\n", item);` and `printf("We stored: %p\n", ordered_list->list[i]);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY i know for sure that won't work. I implemented `fb_printf` and it does not know `%p`. Regular `printf` is not available as this is a bare bones kernel.

Comment: Could you have a bug in your `fb_printf`? Perhaps try using a conditional to check `if (ordered_list->list[i] == 0) fb_printf("bad\n"); else fb_printf("good\n");`. To discount any possible format specifier bugs in your `fb_printf`.

Comment: 1) if the list array contains 'size' entries, the this line: `ordered_list->list[i] = item;` is accessing past the end of the list, this results in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.  2) this function: `place_ordered_list()` is returning a struct that is located on the stack which probably will not work as expected, as  such a struct will go out-of-scope rather than returning the contents of the struct.  3) this line: `void* *list;` is declaring a variable `list` that is a pointer to a pointer to void.  probably not what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out what was causing this issue:

After more testing it became apparent that the memory area 0xe00000 could not be written too. Once I realized this I took a long look at the paging code and found that I was 1 page off in mapping the ROM only area below 1MB. This caused `0xe00000` to `0xe01000` to be mapped to the last physical page at the end of that read-only area (`0xff000`).

Once I corrected the paging code (e.g. `<=` instead of `<`), all functions worked as expected.